# Contains if and only if in the Collection class- Java

Tags: java, collections, dictionary, hashmap

```
Map<String, Integer> successors = new HashMap <String, Integer> ();
// I have added some elements into the successors.
 Collection<Integer> uniqueValues = successors.values();
```

Is there a way for me to find out in java if uniqueValues can show me that all the values in it are the same?

I planned on using the `if(uniqueValues.contains(1))`statement. But I just could not figure it out. Since this statement will say true if 1 is present and other values different from 1 are also present. I just want it to return true if 1 is the only value in the collections.

`eg; {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1} should return true.
But {1,2,1,3,1,4,2,4,22,1,1,1,4} should return false.`

Some code along the lines of **"Contains if and only if."**
This will be of great help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know if English is your first language, but your question is barely understandable as it stands. For starters, "if and only if" has nothing to do with the question. How about simply saying "how can I find out whether a collection contains only one unique object?"

Answer (score 2):

Do it the CPU-clock-wasting way:

```
 if(new HashSet(successors.values()).size()>1) {...}
```

Answer (score 1):

Some sort of `Set` sounds like easiest solution

```
if(new HashSet<Integer>(successors.values)).size() == 1)
```

Because `Set` can contain only unique values, logical consequence of having input collection with same values is the `Set` of size one. Or you can of course introduce you own util method  which will check this condition.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could do something like this (inefficiently),

```
boolean uniqueValues = new HashSet<Integer>(successors.values()).size() == 1;
```

Since that will check every value every time, a more efficient approach might be,

```
boolean uniqueValues = true;
Collection<Integer> values = successors.values();
Iterator<Integer> iter = values.iterator();
if (iter.hasNext()) {
  int t = iter.next();
  while (iter.hasNext()) {
    int i = iter.next();
    if (t != i) {
      // stop if we find a different value
      uniqueValues = false;
      break;
    }
  }   
}
```

Comment: Could be much shortened with *enhanced for* loop.

Comment: `Integer first = null; for (int i : successors.values()) { if (first == null) first = i; else if (i != first) return false; } return true; }`

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik And what if successors contains a few `null` values? Say, `null` and `0`.

Comment: Then it fails. However, no sane program would put nulls in map entries so it's not a real issue.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I started with an enhanced for loop, and came up with the above, because frequently I support insane programs. Regardless, I think I could shorten it a bit as a `do{}while;` but really we're optimizing something that is unlikely to be critical path.

Comment: This is just for code clarity, it will compile to the same bytecode anyway. I don't give up on enhanced for without a good reason, and here I don't see one. Using an extra boolean to track whether this is the first iteration would be enough to cover even for nulls.

Comment: What makes the earlier one inefficient? Are you talking in terms of o(n)?

Comment: They are both O(n) in time, but the first one has a much larger constant factor and is O(n) in space as well (builds up a hashtable). Finally, it does not short-circuit as soon as it finds a different value.